# Counting the number of recursion of a function within the function

Tags: python, function, recursion, iteration

I am working on this function and WITHIN the function I would like to count the number of iterations/recursions of the function in itself. Any and all help would be helpful! Thank you!

```
def runGenerations( L ):
    """ runGenerations keeps running evolve...
    """

    count = 0
    show(L)
    print(L)
    time.sleep(0.05)  

    if allOnes(L) == True:

        return L


    else:

        newL = evolve( L ) 
        return runGenerations( newL ) + 1
```

Comment: You need to somehow keep the state and I'm not sure what your definition of "WITHIN" is, but would adding a new parameter to the function for the count be an option?

Comment: What I mean is that I don't want to add count as another variable like change the function to runGenerations(L,count)

Answer (score 3):

You could pass a `count` argument up your recursive chain:

```
def runGenerations(L, count=1):
    show(L)
    print(L)

    if allOnes(L):
        print("result found after {} attempts".format(count))
        return L

     newL = evolve(L)
     return runGeneratons(newL, count+1) + 1
```

This program really doesn't need to be recursive though. An iterative solution would be:

```
def runGenerations_iterative(L):
    count = 1
    show(L)
    print(L)

    while not allOnes(L):
        L = evolve(L)
        count += 1
        show(L)
        print(L)

    print("result {} found after {} attempts".format(L, count))
    return L + count - 1
```

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that Python has a recursion depth limit.  I think by defaults its set to 1000.  see **sys.getrecursionlimit()** and **sys.setrecursionlimit()**

Comment: @blckknght is there a way to do it without using format(count)?

Comment: @mtadd I adjusted the limit to be higher, but thank you for the warning!

Comment: @user3517740: You mean, can you return the count rather than print it? I suppose you can, though it will make returning the final `L` value more complicated in the recursive version. Is there a reason you are incrementing the return value on each level? That didn't make a whole lot of sense to me (but then, I don't know what the `L` values are).

Comment: @blckknght I am making a function that involves two others:        setNewElement: setNewElement returns the NEW list's ith element where it is a either a  0 or 1 (randomly chosen)



evolve:
~it takes a list of integers and uses the setNewElement function within it to create a new list by adding one to every element in the list using a list comprehension.
Thus, every element in the original list is increased by one.

runGenerations:

~basically this function makes evolve keep going until the list consists of all ones

Comment: If `L` is a list, then the return statements in your original code don't make any sense (you can't add `1` to a list). I think you need to take a moment to think about what you expect the `runGenerations` function to return. Should it just return the count, ignoring the final version of `L`? That's easy! Just change your code to return `1` rather than `L` in the base case and don't use `count` at all. If you want the final version of `L` too, you need to return a tuple, which makes incrementing the count as your unwind the recursion more complicated (you need to unpack and repack the values).

Comment: @Blckknght I wanted it to show the list each time and then also state how many recursion it takes to reach a list of all 1s but I got it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it!

```
def runGenerations( L ):
    """ runGenerations keeps running evolve...
    """

    count = 0
    show(L)
    print(L)
    time.sleep(0.05)  

    if allOnes(L) == True:

        return 0


    else:

        newL = evolve( L ) 
        return 1 + runGenerations( newL )
```